# not getting expected django session id

Tags: django, session, session-variables, ebay-api

Something very strange is causing me much grief and it has to do with Django sessions. Sometimes my code works as expected, and other times it does not.

The workflow I have is this:

User visits URL '/connect/', which resolves to the following function 'get_session_id'. Inside this function,  I obtain an "ebay session id", which is a session ID that the ebay API sends me. After I obtain this "ebay session id", I redirect users to an ebay URL that allows users to validate themselves.

```
import json
import pytz
import requests

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

from ebaysdk.trading import Connection as Trading
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError

def get_session_id(request):
    api = Trading(
        appid="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        devid="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        certid="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        config_file=None,
    )

    res = None
    max_retries = 5
    number_retries = 0
    while number_retries <= max_retries:
        try:
            res = api.execute(
                'GetSessionID',
                {"RuName": "XXXXXXXX"}
            )
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout as exception:
            if number_retries > max_retries:
                raise exception
            number_retries += 1
        except ConnectionError as exception:
            raise Exception('ConnectionError:\n%s' %
                            json.dumps(exception.response.dict(), sort_keys=True, indent=5))
        else:
            break

    redirect_url = "https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&runame=%s&SessID=%s" % \
                   ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", res.reply.SessionID)

    response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to=redirect_url)

    print 'Fetched eBay SessionID: %s' % res.reply.SessionID
    print 'Django Session Key: %s' % request.session._get_session_key()

    request.session['ebay_session_id'] = res.reply.SessionID
    request.session.modified = True

    return response
```

If the user successfully validates, I instruct eBay to direct users back to the 'fetchToken/' URL on my site, which resolves to the following function 'fetch_token'. At this point I need to get the original 'ebay_session_id' that I stored in the request.session / Django session above, but for some reason the Django session key sometimes does not match up! Can someone explain why this is the case???

```
def fetch_token(request):
    api = Trading(
        appid="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        devid="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        certid="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        config_file=None,
    )

    print 'Retrieved eBay SessionID for FetchToken: %s' % request.session['ebay_session_id']
    print 'Django Session Key: %s' % request.session._get_session_key()

    res = None
    max_retries = 5
    number_retries = 0
    while number_retries <= max_retries:
        try:
            res = api.execute(
                "FetchToken",
                {"SessionID": request.session['ebay_session_id']}
            )
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout as exception:
            if number_retries > max_retries:
                raise exception
            number_retries += 1
        except ConnectionError as exception:
            raise Exception('ConnectionError:\n%s' %
                            json.dumps(exception.response.dict(), sort_keys=True, indent=5))
            #return HttpResponse(e.response.dict())
        else:
            break

    expiration_time_aware = res.reply.HardExpirationTime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    EbayTokens.objects.create_ebay_token(eias_token=res.reply.eBayAuthToken,
                                         expiration_time=expiration_time_aware,
                                         user=request.user)
```

My settings file has the following lines to enable sessions, so that's not the problem. I am using Django 1.9.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

As I said, SOMETIMES it works, and sometimes it doesn't. I get the feeling that it stops working when I log in with a user, hit a bug, and then refresh. Please see below for an example when it doesn't work. When I go to "/connect/", I have the Django Session Key that starts with "mxcp...", but then when I instruct eBay to redirect back to "/fetchToken/", I get the key that starts with "4b2b".

It might be interesting to note that in my 'django_session' table, "4b2b.." is the second to last entry, whereas "mxcp..." is the last entry.

```
[21/May/2017 19:17:03] "POST /signup HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Fetched eBay SessionID: skADAA**2c710a5615c0a5f02a54ffe4fffffa58
Django Session Key: mxcpfrtaz2psxf9bp8tb5m2qyknzmw6a
[21/May/2017 19:17:04] "GET /connect/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Retrieved eBay SessionID for FetchToken: skADAA**2c6c73ae15c0a7958d63e7e3fffffa42
Django Session Key: 4b2b2d7shui5qxa593wfnccy6c4fudz5
```

Someone please help, I'll be forever indebted.